# query execution time in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Does anyone know how to display the query execution time in mysql workbench? I am running version 5.2.45 and I cannot see anywhere the time taken by the query to run! What a mistery!

Comment: Isn't there any output view under results view? In Action output, it the right most column with title Duration/Fetch

Answer (score 5):

When you run a query the server response is listed in the output pane below the editor/result set grid. There's a selector to switch between different parts, so make sure you select "Action Output". In this grid you see if a query run successfully or failed, when it ran, the query text, the server response and the query times (time to execute the query and time to retrieve data).

As it turns out sometimes the bottom area can "get lost", that is, it no longer shows up despite the toggle in the toolbar is set to show the "Action Output". In that case it is very likely that the splitter which is hosts the action output as well as the editor and right side bar got in a state where it collapsed the lower part. Try moving your mouse slowly below the bottom tab ("Result 2") until it changes to a split cursor. Then drag the splitter up to make the lower part visible. I have also seen (mostly on Mac) that the cursor does not change, but can still drag the splitter.

Comment: Sorry for "piggy-backing" - posted answer in response to yours. I would be grateful if you could show me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute query in workbench. Ouput Pane is displayed.

In Output Pane, there are columns (time, Action, message etc). The rightmost column is "Duration/Fetch" where duration of execution is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

It is shown as Requested in time(sec.) at the down most